# How do I use ANT to produce a .air file?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex3, air

This is a sample from my build.xml

```
<mxmlc 
    file="${SRC_DIR}/Main.mxml" 
    output="${DEPLOY_DIR}/@{market}.air" 
    locale="@{locale}"
    debug="false" 
    optimize="true">

    <arg value="+configname=air"/>

    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>

    <library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/air" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc" />
    </library-path>

</mxmlc>
```

There are no errors produced when this runs and a .air file is produced but when the .air file is double clicked I get the error message:

"The application could not be installed because the AIR file is damaged. Try obtaining a new AIR file from the application author."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to do this is here: http://blog.devsandbox.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/example_air_build.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AIR compiler (amxmlc) : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=CommandLineTools_2.html

Not sure if they also have an ANT task for this, but it's worth a try.